# Reset select box value to default onChange Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want to clear the select box value when the user selects some value from it. I tried it by changing the state, But it is not working for me. I used the below code:

```
if(e.target.dataset.name==='isActive'){
    if(this.state.isActiveSelected){
      if(e.target.value==='true'){
        alert('You can make only one project active!');
        worksheets[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.dataset.name] = 'false'; 
      }
    }
    if(e.target.value==='true' && (this.state.isActiveSelected===false)){
      this.setState({
        isActiveSelected:true
      })
      worksheets[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.dataset.name] = e.target.value; 
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me the code for this?

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve this

Comment: you can see the edited code.

Comment: Can you post your full code please? with jsx code and events, inshort add code which is relevant to your problem.